# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(t+n)}n$ for $g(t)=\int_0^tf(x)\,dx$, where $f(x+1)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, periodic-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x+1)=f(x) \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Define $g(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^tf(x)\,dx$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h(t)=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(t+n)}{n}$ (provided it exists).
>
> Show that $h(t)$ is defined $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ and is independent of $t$.

As the period of $f$ is $1$, we can say that $\displaystyle\int_0^tf(x)\,dx=t\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$. But what about $\displaystyle\int_0^{t+n}f(x)\,dx$? It is also seen that $g'(t)=f(t)$. How do I find the limit?

Comment: Surely you can say $\int_0^{t+n} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = (t+n) \int_{0}^1 f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: @ZainPatel That's only true if $t+n$ is an integer. See $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I do try to do that every time I post a question. Thanks for editing in this case, I should have thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As the period of $f$ is $1$, we can say that $\displaystyle\int_0^tf(x)\,dx=t\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$

Is false.

For example, take $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$. Then

$$t\cdot\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0=t\cdot 0 = 0$$

while $$\int_0^t f(x)dx$$

is *not* $0$ for all values of $t$.

---

To solve the problem, first define the constant

$$A=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$

Then, you can easily see that

$$g(t)=A\cdot \lfloor t\rfloor + \int_0^{\{t\}} f(x)dx$$

where $\{t\}$ is the *fractional* part of $t$ and $\lfloor t\rfloor$ is the largest integer smaller than $t$.

Once you have $g$ in that shape, both tasks should be simple to solve.

Comment: Isn't $\int_{0}^{nT}f(x)\,dx=n\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\,dx$ where $T$ is the period of  $f$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Only if $T$ is an integer...

Comment: @StubbornAtom I have you a general idea on how to solve the problem, take a look at it and try it yourself! If you are still stuck, you can ask for more help (but first show how far you got, of course)

Comment: $T=1$ here. So I can write that?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, sure, if $T=1$, then you can easily prove (you still have to prove it!) that $$\int_0^n = n\int_0^1 f(x) dx.$$ But since $h(t)$ is defined for all real $t$, you can't limit yourself to integer values...

Comment: @StubbornAtom I don't understand that question.

Comment: If I did limit myself to integer values, then I am getting $h(t)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$ itself.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, if $t$ is an integer, then you are correct that $h(t)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$. But you have to show that $h(t)$ is defined **for all real values of $t$**, and you haven't done that yet. The second part of my answer gives you a relatively big clue about how to solve the problem.

Comment: Nice answer +1. But I think OP's comment that $$\int_{0}^{nT}f\,dx = n\int_{0}^{T}f\,dx$$ is correct if $f$ is periodic with period $T$ and $n$ is an integer. It appears that OP is trying to use this even when $n$ is not an integer. On the other hand you are saying that $T$ needs to be an integer. This I believe is a typo in your comment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Well, technically, it is true if $n$ is an integer and $T$ is an integer multiple of the period of $f$, but since the period is $1$, it is then true if both $n$ and $T$ are integers.

Comment: Ok got it. I was thinking that the comment was about any general $f$ with period $T$ and not about the specific function $f$ here with period $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With Stolz-Ces$\mathrm{\grave{a}}$ro Theorem:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mathrm{h}\pars{t}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\mathrm{g}\pars{t + n} \over n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}
{\mathrm{g}\pars{t + n + 1} - \mathrm{g}\pars{t + n} \over \pars{n + 1} - n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{t + n}^{t + n + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{t}^{t + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x + n}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{t}^{t + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\color{#f00}{\int_{t}^{t + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

---

Moreover,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{h}'\pars{t} & = \totald{}{t}\int_{t}^{t + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x = \mathrm{f}\pars{t + 1} -
\mathrm{f}\pars{t} `= 0\quad\imp\quad
\color{#f00}{\mathrm{h}\pars{t}}\ \mbox{is}\ t\mbox{-independent}
\\[3mm] &\
\mbox{It means}\ \,\mathrm{h}\pars{t} = c = \mbox{constant. In particular,}\
c = \,\mathrm{h}\pars{t} = 
\color{#f00}{\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm] &
\mbox{Indeed,}\
c = \color{#f00}{\,\mathrm{h}\pars{t}} = 
\color{#f00}{\int_{a}^{a + 1}\mathrm{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
\pars{~\mbox{a constant}~}\,,\
\forall\ a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}
\end{align}

Comment: You showed that $h'(t)=0$ whence $h(t)$ must be a constant. But as you showed $h(t)=\int_{t}^{t+1}f(x)\,dx$, so for $h(t)$ to be a constant we set $t=0$. Is this the line of reasoning? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @StubbornAtom It's independent of the $t$-argument. So, you can use any $t$ in order to evaluate the constant value of $\,\mathrm{h}\left(t\right)$. $t = 0$ is just a particular case. Any other value of $t$ yields the same constant value of $\,\mathrm{h}\left(t\right)$. I just rewrote a little my answer after I received your comment. Thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $t$,

$$g(t+n) = \int_0^{t+n} f(x) dx = \int_0^{t} f(x) dx + \int_t^{t+n} f(x) dx =  \int_0^{t} f(x) dx +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{t+i}^{t+i+1} f(x) dx$$

**Lemma**: if a continuous function $f$ has period $T$, then for any $a$,  $\int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = \int_0^T f(x)dx$

**Proof**: Let $F$ denote a primitive of $f$ and let $g:x\to F(x+T)-F(x)$. Note that $g'=0$ hence $g$ is constant. Note also that  $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{a+T} f(x) dx = F(a+t)-F(a) = g(a) = g(0)=\int_0^T f(x)dx$

Hence $\displaystyle g(t+n) = \int_0^{t} f(x) dx +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_0^{t} f(x) dx + n \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$