# $f(x+1) = f(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Let $g(t)=\int_{0}^tf(x)dx$ $h(t)=\lim_{n→\infty}\frac{g(t+n)}n, t∈\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, solution-verification

> **QUESTION:** Consider a real valued continuous function $f$ satisfying $f(x+1) = f(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$. Let
>
> $$g(t)=\int_{0}^tf(x)dx$$ 
>   $$h(t)=\lim_{n→\infty}\frac{g(t+n)}n, t∈\mathbb{R}$$
>   Then--
>
> $(A)$ $h(t)$ is defined only for $t = 0.$
>
> $(B)$ $h(t)$ is defined only when $t$ is an integer.
>
> $(C)$ $h(t)$ is defined for all $t ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and is independent of $t.$
>
> $(D)$ none of the above is true.

---

> *Note that this question has been asked once before but I wish to know how to do it using the approach I have done as shown below..moreover I could not complete this from the hint given before..*

---

**MY ANSWER:** This is what I have done-

*Method 1:*

Simply using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we can say that $g'(t)=f(t)$. Now coming to the limit, using the [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) we can say that $$h(t)=\lim_{n→\infty}f(t+n)$$ Now, we know $f(x+1)=f(x)$. Therefore $f$ is periodic with period $1$. But, my problem is how do I know the value at infinity?

Since $\infty$ is not a number I don't know the value of $f(t+\infty)$. I guess I am missing on something, or could not utilize the periodic information given correctly..

*Method 2:*

$$g(t+n)=\int_{0}^{t+n}f(x)dx$$ Now I cannot write it as $(t+n)\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$ since $(t+n)$ is **not** an integer. So I write $g(t+n)$ as- $$[t+n]\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\{t+n\}}f(x)dx$$ where $[t+n]$ denotes the integer part of $(t+n)$ and $\{t+n\}$ denotes the fractional part of $(t+n)$. Now $\int_{0}^1f(x)dx$ is clearly a constant, so no issues in that. But the problem here is again with $n$. As $n→\infty$ how do I solve for $g(t+n)$ ? The fractional part of $\infty$ is not defined, neither (I guess) is the integer part. How do I tackle this problem then?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the other question?

Comment: @lcv, I saw it once last day, but when I posted mine, it didn't show up.. how do I find it again?

Comment: Your almost there with method 2. Note that $\{t+n\}=\{t\}\in [0,1)$

Comment: @lcv how is that possible when $n→\infty$ ? Infinity is not a number, how do you exclude that altogether?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853069/321264

Comment: The fractional part of 3+ 2.76 is 0.76

Comment: @lcv yes yes I understand that.. in your example $3$ is an integer, but what I am telling is $\infty$ is not an integer.. so how do you apply the same logic to do that?

Comment: Stranger: first take the fractional part *then* take the limit $n\to \infty$

Comment: Didn't get you  @lcv

Comment: @lcv got you.. thanks 

Comment: @StrangerForever Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(n+t)}n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{[n+t]\cdot g(1)+g(\{n+t\})}n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\cdot g(1)+[t]\cdot g(1)+g(\{t\})}n\\
&=g(1)+([t]\cdot g(1)+g(\{t\}))\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}n\\
&=g(1)\end{align} $$

Comment: Will you please tell me how $\{n+t\}=\{t\}$? . Also I have noticed that you have taken the $[\infty]=\infty$, so that can be done right? The second question is just for my knowledge, I didn't know that..